# The set of the limit points and being dense

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Let $A$ be a subset of the metric space $(X,d)$. Is the following statement true?
> $$A' \ \text{is dense in}\  X \iff A \ \text{is dense in}\  X$$Where $A'$ denotes the set of the limit points.

**My try:** I tried to work with some examples. Let $A=\mathbb{Q}$, then $A' = \mathbb{R}$. So in this case the statement is true. If we know $A'$ is dense in $X$, according to the definition, $\text{cl}(A') = X$. Also we have $\text{cl}(A') = A' \cup (A')'$. In addition, if $A$ is dense in $X$, then $\text{cl}(A) = A \cup A' = X$. So it seems that if we find a set $A$ such that $(A')' \not= A$ we can disprove the statement but I couldn't find such set.

Comment: If $X$ is any space with the discrete metric, then $X$ is dense in $X$, but $X'=\varnothing$ is clearly not dense in $X$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks. So the connection between $(A')'$ and $A$ doesn't help us in this problem?

Comment: There isn’t much connection between $(A')'$ and $A$, apart from the fact that $(A')'\subseteq\operatorname{cl}A$. For **Reveillark**’s example, for instance, $A'=\{0\}$, so $(A')'=\varnothing$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $A'$ is dense in $X$. Fix  $x\in X$ and $\varepsilon>0$. By assumption, there is some  $b\in A'$ such that $0<d(x,b)<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Since $b\in A'$, there is some $a\in A$ with $0<d(a,b)<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Note $d(x,a)<\varepsilon$ by the triangle inequality. This shows  that $A$ is dense.

The other implication is false. Let $X=\left\{\frac{1}{n+1}:n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}\cup \{0\}$, with the metric it inherits from $\mathbb R$. Put $A=\left\{\frac{1}{n+1}:n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$. Then $A$ is dense in $X$, but $A'=\{0\}$ is not.